# Reference Error undefined function in Javascript only sometimes

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error "Reference Error undefined function in Javascript on click" but on sometimes.
I almost all its working fine but in few systems giving error. I am not able to find what is the issue why only in some devices. Because if issue was in code then functinality should stop working.

```
 <button style="font-size: 12px;padding: 9px;" type="button" onclick="downloadPDF();" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download</button>

function downloadPDF()
{
  var title = $('#uniqueh5').text();
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var arr = url.split("/");
  var title = arr[2];
  var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  var fontvalue = $('#getfontsize').val();
  $.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   xhrFields: {
          responseType: 'blob'
      },
   url:'/download-judgment',
   data:{id:id , fontvalue:fontvalue},
   beforeSend:function(){
    $('#selectfontdiv').hide();
    $('#downloadbtn').hide();
    $('.modal-header').css("visibility","hidden");
    $('#downloading_judgment_div').show();
   },
   complete:function(){
    $('#selectfontdiv').show();
    $('#downloadbtn').show();
    $('.modal-header').css("visibility","visible");
    $('#downloading_judgment_div').hide();
   },
   success:function(data){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = title + '.pdf';
        document.body.append(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
   }
  });
}
```

I am doing wrong anything please help

Comment: Maybe its because the `append` function is not done with its job when `click` is executed. Can you add a timeout for a few milliseconds before the call to `click` function and check if it works now?

Comment: How are you loading the javascript in html?

Comment: Please provide the *exact* error message. The error should come with a specific line number. Which line in your code is it?

Comment: Hey Prakhar, 
not getting

Comment: Hii Trincot, it says uncaught reference error downloadPDf is not defined on line where button is.

Comment: on this line    <button style="font-size: 12px;padding: 9px;" type="button" onclick="downloadPDF();" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download</button>

Comment: @PrakharSingh `append` is not asynchronous, there's no need for a timeout.

Comment: Hii Amith i have included ajax page in my html.